# Systemd service not work with Runtime Exec Command

Tags: java, exec, systemd

When I run our program with wrapper from systemd service. The program catch the `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "netstat": error=2, No such file or directory` but when I start directly from the wrapper, it won't catch this error and work fine.

We use Runtime Excec command in java 8

```
String command = "netstat -tulpn | grep :" + port;
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

- We have changed all the path of java to absolute path.
- The systemd
  service is running as root
- We can run netstat from centos7 on root
- Shebang has been added

[Cannot run program "netstat"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHafA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really inconvenient but I had to change netstat's path to absolute then the problem seems to be solved. But on different servers, netstat is in a different path.